# How to inflate in Python some data that was deflated by Peoplesoft (Java)?

Tags: java, guid, deflate, inflate, peoplesoft

**DISCLAIMER: Peoplesoft knowledge is not mandatory in order to help me with this one!**

How could i extract the data from that Peoplesoft table, from the PUBDATALONG column?
The description of the table is here: 
http://www.go-faster.co.uk/peopletools/psiblogdata.htm

Currently i am using a program written in Java and below is a piece of the code:

```
Inflater inflater = new Inflater();
byte[] result = new byte[rs.getInt("UNCOMPDATALEN")];
inflater.setInput(rs.getBytes("PUBDATALONG"));
int length = inflater.inflate(result);

System.out.println(new String(result, 0, length, "UTF-8"));
System.out.println();
System.out.println("-----");
System.out.println();
```

How could I rewrite this using Python? 
It is a question that appeared in other forms on Stackoverflow but had no real answer.
I have basic understanding of what the code does in Java but i don't know any library in Python i could work with to achieve the same thing.

Some recommended to try zlib, as it is compatible with the algorithm used by Java Inflater class, but i did not succeed in doing that.
**Considering the below facts from PeopleSoft manual:**

> When the message is received by the PeopleSoft database, the XML data
>   is converted to UTF-8 to prevent any UCS2 byte order issues. It is
>   also compressed using the deflate algorithm prior to storage in the
>   database.

I tried something like this:

```
import zlib
import base64


UNCOMPDATALEN = 362 #this value is taken from the DB and is the dimension of the data after decompression.
PUBDATALONG = '789CB3B1AFC8CD51284B2D2ACECCCFB35532D43350B2B7E3E5B2F130F40C8977770D8977F4710D0A890F0E710C090D8EF70F0D09080DB183C8BAF938BAC707FBBBFB783ADA19DAE86388D904B90687FAC0F4DAD940CD70F67771B533B0D147E6DAE8A3A9D5C76B3F00E2F4355C=='


print zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(PUBDATALONG), 0, 362)
```

and I get this:

> zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

for sure I do something wrong but I am not smart enough to figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string is not Base-64 encoded. It is simply hexadecimal. (I have no idea why it ends in `==`, which makes it look a little like a Base-64 string.) You should be able to see by inspection that there are no lower case letters, or for that matter upper case letters after `F` as there would be in a typical Base-64 encoded string of compressed, i.e. random-appearing data.

Remove the equal signs at the end and use `.decode("hex")` in Python 2, or `bytes.fromhex()` in Python 3.

Comment: i added that == at the end, my bad. 
i will try to do what you recommended and let you know.

thank you.